# Why does the cast operator to a private base not get used?

Tags: c++, inheritance, casting, implicit-conversion, explicit-conversion

In this code assigning to b1 works, but it won't allow assigning to b2 (with or without the static cast). I was actually trying to solve the opposite problem, public inheritance but not implicitly converting to the base. However the cast operator never seems to be used. Why is this?

```
struct B {};    

struct D1 : private B {
    operator B&() {return *this;}
    B& getB() {return *this;}
};

struct D2 : public B {
    explicit operator B&() {return *this;}
};

struct D3 : public B {
    operator B&() = delete;
};

void funB(B& b){}

int main () {
  D1 d1;
  funB(d1.getB()); // works
  // funB(d1); // fails to compile with 'inaccessible base class
  D2 d2;
  funB(d2); // works
  D3 d3;
  funB(d3); // works 
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I can't replicate the compilation error you describe.

Comment: @Peter: Replicated [here](http://ideone.com/hKSEAo)

Comment: @Barabas: I'll wait for someone with an appropriate quote from the standard to provide the answer, but think of public inheritance as "is-a" and private inheritance as "has-a". I.e., `D2` and `D3` are special instances of `B`, whereas `D1` is it's own thing that happens to *have* a `B`.

Comment: What is the point of "private" inheritance here?

Comment: There doesn't have to be a point. This could be a MCVE of real world code or it could just be code written to expand understanding of the C++ standard.

Comment: @lulyon I was just trying around. I mainly want to inherit without implicitly converting to the base class, but explicit conversion would be ok. I guess it's impossible.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From [[class.conv.fct]](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.conv.fct#1):

> A conversion function is never used to convert a (possibly cv-qualified) object
>   to the (possibly cv-qualified) same object type (or a reference to it), **to a (possibly cv-qualified) base class of that type (or a reference to it)**, or to (possibly cv-qualified) void.

So in your first example:

```
struct D1 : private B {
    operator B&() {return *this;}
    B& getB() {return *this;}
};
```

`operator B&` will never be used because it converts to a base class. It doesn't matter that it's a private base class.

Comment: So if I understand it correctly it's impossible to inherit while having explicit conversion, but not implicit, right?

Comment: @Barabas Not sure what you are asking.

Comment: Either you inherit publicly and your class will implicitly convert to it's base, or you inherit privately (or protected) and it won't convert at all, not even with a static_cast/constructor. There is no way around it, right?